# Adding two string together node-sass

Tags: css, fonts, gruntjs, node-sass

I'm trying to create a mixin named `getFont` to simplify the `@font-face` call. With compass and sass I do this:

```
@mixin getFont($name, $url){
  @font-face {
    font-family: $name;
    src: url($url+".eot");
    src: url($url+".eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
      url($url+".woff") format("woff"), 
      url($url+".ttf") format("truetype"), 
      url($url+".svg#") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
```

Which gives me the desired result using compass, but while using grunt and node-sass I get this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font-name';
  src: url($url+".eot");
  src: url($url+".eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url($url+".woff") format("woff"), url($url+".ttf") format("truetype"), url($url+".svg#") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

Looks like the compiler is having some trouble adding two strings together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used grunt oder node-sass, so you will have to do the testing. 
This works in compass, like your attemp. Maybe this will lead to the desired result in the other system as well.

```
@mixin getFont($name, $url){
  @font-face {
    font-family: $name;
    src: url(#{$url}.eot);
    src: url(#{$url}.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
    url(#{$url}.woff) format("woff"),
    url(#{$url}.ttf) format("truetype"),
    url(#{$url}.svg#) format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle, with a broken font. You need to run this in the /draft modus: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/LKJK6/2/ to see the CSS result (rules are broken)

Comment: Yup thats what I ended up figuring out. Was just coming back to update the question!